# How to convert a string into a char matrix

Tags: c++, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I want to put a string into a char nxn matrix, which makes the string `"abcdefghi"` into a `3x3` char matrix, and become 
{abc;def;ghi}
but it does not save right.

I try to output every `i`, `j`,`ch[i][j]` and `s[j+i*3]` in the first loop, and they look right, but in the final output, it goes wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char ch[2][2];
    string s = "abcdefghi";
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            ch[i][j] = s[j + i * 3];
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << ch[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want the ch matrix become
{abc;def;ghi}
but the output is 
{abdegi;degi;gi}

Comment: Maybe the final output is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has two problems:
1. `char ch[2][2];` is supposed to be `char ch[3][3];`
2. You assume you can print an entire row with a single `cout << ch[i] << endl;`, but the rows don't end with a `'\0'`, thus `cout` prints everything until it hits a null.

Here's a fixed version:

```
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    char ch[3][3];
    auto s = "abcdefghi";
    auto* ptr = s;
    for (auto& r1 : ch)
    {
        for (auto& r2 : r1)
        {
            r2 = *ptr++;
        }
    }

    for (const auto& r1 : ch)
    {
        for (auto r2 : r1) // char is trivial to copy
        {
            std::cout << r2;
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << std::flush;
    return 0;
}
```